# Bartle Theorem 6.14 Completeness of $L_p$ (Riesz Representation) - need explanation 2

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, proof-explanation, integral-inequality

This is a follow up post to my previous [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073714/bartles-theorem-6-14-completeness-of-lp-riesz-representation-need-explana). I am piecing parts of the Completeness in $L_p$ proof. I have labelled parts I am unsure of $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$. I have argued why they are true. However, it was messy as I had to check *each condition of DCT*.

I hope one could check my argument or give a clean argument to the three parts.

> We now define $f$ on $X$ by 
>   $$ f(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad = g_1(x) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (g_{k+1}(x) -g_k(x) ), \quad x \in E, $$ 
>   $$ = 0 , \quad \quad x \notin E. $$ 
>   Since $|g_k| \le |g_1| + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} |g_{j+1} -g_j|  \le g $ and since $\color{blue}{\text{converges $(g_k)$ a.e. to $f$} \quad (1) }$, $\color{blue}{\text{the Dominated Convergence Theorem implies that $f \in L_p$.} \quad \quad (2)}$
>
> Since $|f- g_k|^p \le 2^pg^p,$ $ \color{blue}{\text{ we infer from the DCT that $0 = \lim ||f -g_k||_p$, so that $(g_k)$ converges in $L_p$ to $f$. } \quad \quad (3) }$
>
> If $m \ge M(\varepsilon)$ and $k$ is sufficiently large, then 
>   $$ \int |f_m - g_k|^p \, d \mu < \varepsilon^p . $$ 
>   Apply Fatou's Lemma to conclude that 
>   $$ \int |f_m - f|^p \, d \mu \le \lim \inf _{k \rightarrow \infty} \int | f_m - g_k| ^p \, d \mu \le \varepsilon^p.$$
>   whenever $m \ge M(\varepsilon)$. This proves that the sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in the norm of $L_p$.

---

**How I would argue**

**(1):**  As $g(x) := |g_1(x)| + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |g_{k+1}(x) -g_k(x)| <+\infty $ on $E$, we know the series converges absolutely, hence the series in $f$ converges on $E$. So $(g_k)$ converges a.e. to $f$ on $E$.

**(2):** By continuity $|g_k|^p$ converges a.e. to $|f|^p$ on $E$. We know that by definition $g_k \in L_p$ so $\int |g_k|^p \, d \mu < \infty$  and $|g_k|^p$ is integrable.

It has been shown that $|g_k|^p \le |g|^p $ where $|g|^p$ is integrable. Hence, the conditions of DCT are satisfied, we then obtain,

$$ \int |f|^p \, d \mu \stackrel{DCT}{=}   \lim \int |g_k|^p \, d \mu \le \lim \int |g|^p \, d \mu < + \infty .$$

Since $f$ is limit of measurable functions, it is measurable. So $f \in L_p$.

**(3):** Apply DCT on the sequence of functions: $(|f-g_k|^p)$. We first note that they are integrable, since $|f-g_k|$ is measurable and $\phi(x) = x^p$ is a continuous map, $\phi(f-g_k) = |f-g_k|^p$ is measurable.

Also, as $|f-g_k|^p \le 2^p g^p$, and the RHS is integrable, we deduce that $|f-g_k|^p$ is integrable. We have previously shown that $|f-g_k|^p \rightarrow 0 $ a.e. So by DCT, 
$$ 0 \stackrel{DCT}{=} \lim \int \, |f-g_k|^p \, d \mu = \lim ||f - g_k ||_p^p $$
But as $\phi(x)=x^p$ is continuous, we deduce 
$$ \lim ||f-g_k||_p = 0 .$$

**Summary:**

I would like to know how one *writes a clean argument in this case*, and why the author states as though all conditions of DCT are trivially satisfied.

Thanks in advance.

---

> *Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.* Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of integrable functions which converges almost everywhere to a real valued measurable function $f$. If there exists an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n| \le g$ for al $n$, then $f$ is integrable and 
>   $$ \int f \, d \mu = \lim \int f_n \, d \mu .$$

**PS:** How do I append "hide" bars. As I would like to include the whole proof, but it would take up the whole page.

Comment: (1) Your argument is essentially correct. In fact, $g_k \to f$ **everywhere** in $E$. And since $X \setminus E$ has measure zero (established in your previous post), this means that $g_k \to f$ almost everywhere in $X$. (2) and (3) look right to me.

I don't think you should be concerned that your argument is not "clean" or that you had to provide some missing details. Probably Bartle has deliberately written the proof in the expectation that you will fill in these details.

Comment: @Bungo, thanks a lot. I have just one last question: I don't see where the result (from $(3)$) " $ \lim || f - g_k || _p = 0 $" was needed for the final step. In fact, if we had that result we didn't even need to use Fatou's Lemma for the final step. We could argue by $ || f - f_n ||_p \le || f _n - g_k || _p + ||g_k - f|| _p  \rightarrow 0 $ by Minkowski's Inequality (which was proven already). What am I missing? Thanks so much.

Comment: I think your argument using Minkowski's inequality is fine. We have $\|g_k - f\|_p \to 0$ as proved above, and we have $\|f_n - g_k\|_p \to 0$ as $n$ and $k$ both increase, because $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^p$ and $(g_k)$ is a subsequence of $(f_n)$.

Comment: Ok, but what I don't understand was where the result $\lim || f- g_k||_p = 0 $ was actually used in the original proof. Because if we delete line (3), the proof is not affected. Is this right?

Comment: I think it is implicitly used in the last line. Try writing out in detail a proof that $\int|f_m - f|^p d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty}\int |f_m - g_k|^p d\mu$. Can you do it without having already established that $\lim \|f - g_k\|_p = 0$?

Comment: @Bungo, yes sorry, you are right. I was confused. Thank you so much.